# How can I decrease the ringtone/notification volume on my Oppo Find 7?

Tags: notifications, ringtone, volume, oppo-coloros, oppo-find-7

I recently got this device and so far ColorOS is virtually indistinguishable from stock Android.  The only problem is that the ringer and notification sound are insanely loud, even on the very lowest setting before silent, as is the System volume.  Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've figured out that you can do this by rooting and editing the `system` table in `settings.db` (/data/data/com/android.providers.settings/databases).  I used [SQLite Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.sqleditor) for this.

I am not completely certain which of the two did the trick, but I edited both `volume_system` and `volume_notification` and now my texts are a reasonable volume.

Comment: You are my personal Jesus Christ. This (by extension) helped me get over (or rather under) the ridiculous lower limit of 85% on font size.

Comment: @SixthOfFour Hahaha, that's great.  Glad to help!

Comment: Honestly, the font size has been the most severe annoyance ever since I got my first mobile phone back in '94. I don't want 12pt Helvetica Bold on my phone, not even on the 5.1" screen I have today. 12-14pt is what I use on my 30" computer monitor. I've learned to live with that annoyance. Now I can unlearn it. Thanks a gazillion!